# Website(WP) not working on several locations in country(Latvia)

Tags: wordpress, location, ip

we have a problem with connection to our website. the problem is the website not working on several locations in our country(accross the country LATVIA). the website built on Wordpress
link: https://m-lux.lv/
our clients sending error images which not working website.. we dont know excatly on which providers.
no problem with hosting server company..(they said that everything is ok by their side)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a DNS problem.

Please check this https://dnschecker.org/#A/m-lux.lv out with your provider.